# Inicializar lista combobox WPF

Tags: c#, lista, wpf, combobox

La cuestión es la siguiente: yo quiero mostrar un comboBox (eso me lo hace) lo que yo quiero es que cuando se cargue mi vista con todos los controles en el combo(dtp_mes)
el texto que aparezca inicialmente sea [seleccionar] en lugar del primer dato del item es decir que no se ingrese a la lista que estoy manejando para llenar el combo...

```
        List<string> mes = new List<string>();
        mes.Add("Seleccionar Mes");
        mes.Add("Enero");
        mes.Add("Febrero");
        mes.Add("Marzo");
        this.view.dtp_Mes.ItemsSource = mes;
        this.view.dtp_Mes.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

de esta forma lleno mi combo lo que quiero es omitir el Item en lista que dice Seleccionar Mes, es decir no agregarlo a la lista pero en tiempo de ejecución mi combo Muestre el titulo por default Seleccionar Mes.

Al principio lo supuse fácil, pero ya llevo rato y no va.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias ver si las propiedades `IsEditable` y `Text` resuelven el problema

[XAML ComboBox IsEditable and Text Properties](https://www.reflectionit.nl/blog/2018/xaml-combobox-iseditable-and-text-properties)

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox1"
          IsEditable="True"
          Text="Seleccionar Mes">

</ComboBox>
```

intenda definiendo el `Text` con `IsEditable="True"`

Comment: Excelente, Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar un `WatermarkComboBox` del paquete **[Extended WPF Toolkit](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit)**.
Se puede instalar desde la consola de paquetes NuGet de la siguiente forma:

```
Install-Package Extended.Wpf.Toolkit
```

Posteriormente, en tu código XAML agregas el control,

```
<Window x:Class="Prueba1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Prueba1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <xctk:WatermarkComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            Watermark="Seleccionar mes"/>
</Grid>
```

En el XAML puedes incluir la propiedad `Watermark` de una sola vez (también se puede realizar desde código).
Ya que `WatermarkComboBox` hereda directamente de `ComboBox`, puedes seguir usando el código que tenías para llenar los datos (simplifiqué un poco el código).

```
var mes = new List<string> {
    "Enero",
    "Febrero",
    "Marzo"
    };
comboBox.ItemsSource = mes;
//comboBox.Watermark = "También puedes establecer por código la propiedad";
```

Y el resultado es el siguiente:

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

El texto por default se puede colocar del siguiente modo, sin extensiones ni cosas raras:

```
<ComboBox Name="dtp_Mes"
 IsEditable="True"
 IsReadOnly="True"
 Text="Seleccionar Mes" />
```

Saludos.